# How to show other module system config setting under catalog section configuration

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, admin, xml, system.xml

I have a requirement is that,have an module it  some have system setting which are manged from admin system configuration.
I want show the section under Catalog setting.
Just like...
System>Configuration> Catalog
In Catalog tabs under  below tabs  available-

```
Catalog
Inventory
Google Sitemap
RSS Feeds 
 Email to a Friend
```

**I want to add another tab "Amit"**

```
 Catalog
   Inventory
 Google Sitemap
 RSS Feeds 
 Email to a Friend
Amit
```

Pleas help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In extension etc/system.xml add this xml config

```
<config>
<sections>
    <amit_section translate="label">
        <label>Amit</label>
        <tab>catalog</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>991</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <general translate="label">
                <label>General settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <enabled translate="label">
                        <label>Enable Amit</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </enabled>
                </fields>
            </general>
        </groups>
    </amit_section>
</sections>
</config>
```